# Are there examples (current or historical) of commercial aircraft seating arrangments beyond the standard today?

Tags: airline-operations

Excluding various first-class seating arrangements, are there any examples in history or today, of an airline that has implemented a non-standard seating arrangement?

For instance, most military transport aircraft contain just rows with passengers' shoulders inline with the bow and aft. Are there any examples of where a commercial airline has tried this arrangement -or any other type?

An extreme example would be an airline like a subway car (everyone standing up, just hanging on to something).

Comment: Subways are used to travel shorter distances, and they go at a much slower speed. Airplanes can be compared with intercity trains for a closer comparison in seating configuration.

Comment: That subway car position could happen on Soviet airliners - passengers sometimes got up during descent and were standing in the aisle during landing, so they could leave the aircraft sooner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the old flying boats had a seemingly haphazard arrangement

[image]
[image]

[Source](http://socks-studio.com/2010/11/07/flying-boats/)

[image]

[Source](http://www.seattlepi.com/business/boeing/article/Things-people-leave-on-airplanes-3720648.php)

[image]

[Source](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dornier_Do_X)

But maybe all flying boat passengers were effectively first class?

Comment: Great collection of pictures! Reminds me of the seating on Zeppelins, especially the last one.

Comment: yes, you're showing the first class cabins. Flying boats (at least the big ones) were used effectively like passenger liners. Day cabin, dining room, and passenger cabins with bunks (or seating arrangements like in the picture you show, probably a shorter range one).

Comment: The pictures are great, but yes, these are essentially 1st class (well, they put first class to shame really).

Answer (score 4):

Current FAA passenger safety regulations require seats with 16G survivability:
http://www.faa.gov/passengers/fly_safe/safety_improvements/media/FAA-FactSheet-Aircraft-Survivability.pdf

As the PDF notes:

> In 1988, the FAA issued regulations
>   requiring that all newly developed
>   transport aircraft use “16g” seats.
>   Using a test dummy, these seats
>   undergo dynamic testing and
>   evaluation regarding injury
>   protection. Similar to automobile
>   crash tests, the FAA tests are
>   designed specifically for the aviation
>   environment. Previously, seats were
>   designed and approved to a static
>   9g standard with no occupant
>   injury criteria. Most transport
>   airplanes were developed before
>   1988. However, Amendment
>   121-315, effective October 27,
>   2005, required that transport
>   category airplanes in part 121
>   operations, certificated after
>   January 1, 1958 and manufactured
>   on or after October 27, 2009, must
>   comply with the 16g dynamic
>   standard. In 2010, the agency
>   published guidance on the
>   importance of analyzing how interior
>   structures, such as seats, interact
>   with other structures due to critical
>   loads. In July 2012, the FAA issued
>   new criteria for side-facing seats
>   that are equivalent to the occupant
>   protection for standard
>   forward-facing seats

It is very hard to design side-facing seats that meet these survivability standards (human necks are very weak in the lateral direction). Furthermore, the airplanes are current designed with seats that slide on tracks in order to make the cabins easily customizable to customer (airplane company) requirements. This also makes it easier to design around front-facing seats:

[image]

And let us not forget this quickly abandoned proposal. Everyone would still be facing forward but we'd be standing! With shoulder and waist harnesses (five point), survivability might actually be pretty good! Actually, I'd want a head and neck retainer too. :-)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if those are excluded by the "Excluding various first-class seating arrangements" part of your question, but there are a few slightly more original layouts that have been used (or are still used) by some airlines, mostly for business class:

- the [herringbone pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herringbone_seating). Seats are arranged at about 45° from the axis, and all seats get direct access to the aisle.
- reversed seating, as for instance in British Airways' Club World (business class): in a given row, alternating rear- and forward-facing seats. This saves a bit of space laterally (you need more space at the elbow level than for the legs, so by having one person's elbows be at the level of another's legs, you can have more seats in the same width).